# C# Windows Forms ComboBox's SelectionChangeCommitted event prevents selection change when Combobox's BindingSource property changed in it

Tags: winforms, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, combobox, selecteditemchanged

Using C# Entity Framework objects like below 2

item:

- itemname
- itemtypeid
- itemprice
- itemsize

itemtype:

- typeid
- typename
- currentprice
- typesize

On item edit form there is a combobox called typeidComboBox bound to item.itemtypeid and item list datasource loading from itemtype datasource.

When Form Loads Binding Sources will set like.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        db = new dbtestEntities();
        itemtypeBindingSource.DataSource = db.usertypes;
        itemBindingSource.DataSource = db.users;

        typeidComboBox.DataBindings.Clear();
        typeidComboBox.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue", this.itemBindingSource, "itemtypeid", true));
        typeidComboBox.DataSource = this.itemtypeBindingSource;
        typeidComboBox.DisplayMember = "typename";
        typeidComboBox.ValueMember = "typeid";
        typeidComboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted += typeidComboBox_SelectionChangeCommitted;
    }
```

The problem raise when I add some code like below in SelectionChangeCommitted event.

Code:

```
private void typeidComboBox_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (itemBindingSource.Current as item).itemprice = (itemtypeBindingSource.Current as itemtype).currentprice;
    }
```

Why Combobox selection cancelling and backing to old value when SelectionChangeCommitted event handled like Combobox's BindingSource property changed in it?

Sorry my English.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why. But it solved my problem: DataBinding.WriteValue and ComboBox.SelectedItem.

Here is my working code.

```
private void typeidComboBox_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Binding binding in (sender as ComboBox).DataBindings)
        {
            binding.WriteValue();
        }
    (itemBindingSource.Current as item).itemprice = ((sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem as itemtype).currentprice;
}
```